# Easy way of checking signature of a source package from the other release of debian

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze, gpg, digital-signatures

I'm trying to backport `nanomsg` from `jessie` to `squeeze`. But when I run:

```
dget http://http.debian.net/debian/pool/main/n/nanomsg/nanomsg_0.4~beta+dfsg-3.dsc
```

It says:

```
dscverify: nanomsg_0.4~beta+dfsg-3.dsc failed signature check:
gpg: Signature made Fri 29 Aug 2014 09:49:58 PM EEST using RSA key ID 864CC8BF
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
Validation FAILED!!
```

I saw people suggesting installing `debian-keyring` from that particular release by adding corresponding line to `sources.list` and [`APT::Default-Release "stable";` to `apt.conf`](https://superuser.com/a/886895/185665). But I'm concerned about it polluting my system with packages from the other release.

And if we're talking about `squeeze` here. I can't put `stable` in `apt.conf`, can I? Since `stable` is `jessie` now. And if I put `squeeze` there, it's one more thing to not forget when upgrading `debian`.

I'd like it if I could just safely download `debian-keyring` from `jessie` and add `keyring /path/to/debian-keyring.gpg` to `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` (or [setting `DSCVERIFY_KEYRINGS`](https://askubuntu.com/a/215008/186999)?) to make it work. Is it possible? How should I go about the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily download the debian-keyring package from jessie, and install it with `dpkg -i debian-keyring*deb`. Downsides to that method, however:

- No automatic updates
- No gpg verification

If you want those, you need to use apt to install the packages. Using `APT::Default-Release` is indeed one option; another is apt pinning. Create the file `/etc/apt/preferences.d/99-keyring` with the following contents:

```
Package: debian-keyring
Pin: release n=jessie
Pin-Priority: 600

Package: *
Pin: release n=jessie
Pin-Priority: 50
```

This will tell your system that you want to pull the `debian-keyring` package from jessie, but everything else from your normal distribution. If you don't want to use the code name but want to use the symbolic name instead, change `Pin: release n=jessie` to `Pin: release a=stable`.

See `man apt_preferences` for the full story, including how `APT::Default-Release` ties into all that.

Warning: when used incorrectly, apt pinning may result in a system halfway upgraded between two releases. The above examples should be safe, but don't use it to architecture-specific packages.

Comment: Could you elaborate on avoiding halfway upgraded system, and what architecture-specific packages has to do with it? By architecture-specific you mean architecture-dependent packages?

Comment: Look [what I've found](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto#Recommended_alternative_to_pinning). Why don't we add just `deb-src` line to `sources.list`, download source package, build it and use the keyring as I stated in the question?

Comment: because you don't need to, at least not for `_all.deb` files :-) but yeah, that's also a way that should work.

Comment: Because I don't need to what?

Comment: If it's a `_all.deb` package, you don't need to rebuild it to be able to install it on older releases of Debian (unless it has a dependency that can't be resolved in that older distribution, but that's unusual). You can, sure, but there's usually no need; the result will be the same.